# Showing message dialog in ItemListener prevents checkbox selection

Tags: java, swing, messagebox, event-dispatch-thread

I noticed that when using a message box in an `ItemListener` when selecting a checkbox, it will prevent the checkbox from becoming selected. Here is a full example demonstrating the problem:

```
import javax.swing.*;

import static java.awt.event.ItemEvent.SELECTED;
import static javax.swing.JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE;
import static javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog;

public class ExampleFrame extends JFrame
{
    private ExampleFrame()
    {
        JCheckBox jCheckBox = new JCheckBox("Fail");
        add(jCheckBox);

        jCheckBox.addItemListener(itemEvent ->
        {
            int stateChange = itemEvent.getStateChange();
            if (stateChange == SELECTED)
            {
                showMessageDialog(rootPane,
                        "The checkbox selection did not work.",
                        "SSCCE",
                        INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] arguments)
    {
        ExampleFrame exampleFrame = new ExampleFrame();
        exampleFrame.pack();
        exampleFrame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

What would be best practise to fix this code to make it show the message box and does not break selecting the checkbox?

I had success with using an additional thread to execute the listener, delay it by e.g. `100` milliseconds and then execute the message box again on the `EDT`. This seems too hacky to be considered a proper solution though.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29186464) question is related but did not receive a decent answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Surround your modal dialog with `SwingUtilities.invokeLater`

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        showMessageDialog(rootPane,
            "The checkbox selection did not work.",
            "SSCCE",
            INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    }
});
```